# Por que quando a pagina carrega o evento é disparado?

Tags: javascript, html

É apenas um teste, queria quando eu clicasse na tabela me mostrasse uma mensagem, mas quando a pagina é carregada o evento é disparado, queria saber o por que disso está acontecendo

Meu código

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="t">   
           <tr><td id="t1">one</td></tr>   
           <tr><td id="t2">two</td></tr>   
        </table>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.querySelector('#t').addEventListener('click', alert('ola mundo'), false);
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 6):

Diogo, o segundo parâmetro do método `addEventListener` espera uma função que será executada toda vez que o evento for disparado. Ao passar apenas o `alert('ola mundo')` este trecho é interpretado e executado retornando `void`, ou seja, nada. Essa interpretação ocorre assim que sua linha, ...addEventListener..., é interpretada pelo navegador. Por esta razão ele emite o alerta logo que a página é carregada.

Para resolver o problema:

```html
<table id="t">   
  <tr><td id="t1">one</td></tr>   
  <tr><td id="t2">two</td></tr>   
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.querySelector('#t').addEventListener('click', function() { alert('ola mundo') }, false);
</script>
```